# Velocity and $foreach.count

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

I am using velocity 1.7 and within a foreach loop I want to print the count. In the template I have the following string in a #foreach/#end section:

```
Count: $foreach.count
```

and was expecting to see in the rendered result something like

```
Count: 1
...
Count: 2
...
```

but all I see is:

```
Count: $foreach.count
...
Count: $foreach.count
...
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please add the complete foreach statement?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code is partial, we don't see the foreach directive.

Else, I know that the foreach loop has a built-in variable called `$counter`, though in the guide they do refer to `$foreach.count`

Comment: In Velocity < 1.7 there was a way to configure the name of the counter variable using "directive.foreach.counter.name = velocityCount" in the properties that initialized the engine (this was from the default version). It looks like they've removed the ability to do that change and have named it specifically ${foreach.counter}.

Comment: I'm used to using the formal notation ... a little more verbose but for the most part exposing clarity.

Comment: I am using velocity engine 2.1 and ${foreach.count} works.

Answer (score 33):

Neither `$foreach.count` nor `$counter` worked for me.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791075/velocity-passing-current-forloop-variable-to-another-template/7791837#7791837) suggests using `$velocityCount`, and it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me too. We are using velocity 1.5 and due to using third party framework we can not move to 1.7

Answer (score 12):

I tried with `$counter` & `$foreach.count` but neither of these worked for me.

However, the `$velocityCount` tag worked and below is the example.

**Input code:**

```
#foreach($entry in $entries)    
    <p>In for Loop count is : $velocityCount</p>     
#end
```

**Output:**

```
In for Loop count is : 1

In for Loop count is : 2

In for Loop count is : 3
```

Answer (score 7):

I do not know why  the foreach loop  built-in variable called $count is not working as  guide refer. But  $velocityCount is worked for me.

There is property called directive.foreach.counter.name is  velocityCount in velocity.properties file, so default $count variable may not be working.

Answer (score 7):

k.honsalis answer is deprecated.

At this point you can only use $velocityCount, even though the documentation will refer to deprecated methods.

```
#foreach($item in $items)
counter 0: $foreach.index
counter 1: $foreach.count
counter 2: $counter
counter 3: $velocityCount
#end

Output:

$foreach.index
$foreach.count
$counter
1
```

Comment: This answer makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The default variable is velocityCount, but you can change the variable name and initial value (only in prior 2.0 versions) if you want.

```
VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
engine.setProperty("directive.foreach.counter.name", "velocityCount");
engine.setProperty("directive.foreach.counter.initial.value", 1);
```

http://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/htmlsingle/VelocityUsersGuide.html

Answer (score 2):

I am currently formatting my `email_html.vm` like so.

Note, I am using

`#set( $count = 1 )`
and
`#set( $count = $count + 1 )`

```
<html>
<body>
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse">
    #set( $count = 1 )
    #foreach( $film in $filmList )
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 style="background: bisque; text-align: center"><b>Movie $count</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px; text-align: left">Title</th>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px; text-align: left"> $film.getTitle() </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px; text-align: left">Synopsis</th>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px; text-align: left"> $film.getSynopsis() </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px; text-align: left">Trailer</th>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px; text-align: left"> $film.getTrailerLink() </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px; text-align: left">More Information</th>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px; text-align: left">
                https://www.landmarktheatres.com/$film.getMoreInfoLink() </td>
        </tr>
        #set( $count = $count + 1 )
    #end
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`$velocityCount` is works for me and i'm using velocity 1.5 `$foreach.count` & `$counter`

Answer (score 1):

`$foreach.count` (starts with `1`) and `$foreach.index` (starts with `0`) worked for me with *Velocity 2.3*.

More available loop variables are mentioned in the [docs](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/user-guide.html#foreach-loop).